# Selenium webscrape won't work after different methods tried

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The exact page I'm trying to scrape is: https://www.footasylum.com/page/search/?term=Nike%20Air%20Force%201

Selenium currently works well by finding the search bar and using it, the above page is what is displayed and I now want to retrieve all the product names and prices, I've tried loads of methods but it wont work.

Method 1, XPATH:

```
product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="listing-productname"]')
product_list = []
for p in range(len(product)):
product_list.append(product[p].text)
print(product_list)
```

Which doesn't work as when I try to print both product_list or product itself... it is returned as empty [].

Method 2, class name:

```
product = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('listing-productname')
print(product)
```

also returns nothing, just []

Method 3, class name, but another one:

```
product = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-width')
print(product)
```

also returns nothing.

Method 3, class name, but another class:

```
shoe_name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('listing-productname')
print(shoe_name)
```

also nothing.

Unsure what to now as I feel like I'm starting use all the elements available and whether I use XPATH or class name, I still get nothing returned, just [].

Also - there are no errors, according to the terminal the code has worked fine, it's just not printing anything which I presume means it's obviously not finding anything?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and able to help me out? I also want to retrieve the product price and also struggling in the same way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your method 1, xpath is not locating the web elements, so you are getting an empty list.

Method 2 however is correct, but that requires a tweak :

```
product = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('listing-productname')
for p in product:
    print(p.text)
```

should print 20 items names, because `listing-productname` this represent 20 web elements.

or I would rather have this code to scrape, all the names, and price :

```
names = []
price = []
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@data-nq-product-name]"):
  names.append(name.text)
  price.append(name.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-nq-product-name]/../../following-sibling::div").text)

print(names, price)
```

PS : you are not getting any **error**, since you are using `find_elements`, it would either return a list of web element or an empty list.

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.footasylum.com/page/search/?term=Nike%20Air%20Force%201")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.cookie-container i"))).click()
names = []
price = []
i = 1
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@data-nq-product-name]"):
  names.append(name.text)
  price.append(name.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//span[@data-nq-product-name]/../../following-sibling::div)[{i}]").text)
  i = i + 1

print(names, price)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
['Air Force 1 Low SOS Trainer', 'Air Force 1 LV8 Trainer', 'Junior Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Junior Air Force 1 GS ‘Bred’ Low Trainer', 'Air Force 1 Low Trainer', "Air Force 1 LV8 'Brooklyn Splatter' Trainer", 'Junior Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Infant Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Junior Air Force 1 Crater Flyknit Trainer', 'Infant Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Womens Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Air Force 1 Mid Trainer', "Junior Air Force 1 Low 'Space Jam' Trainer", 'Air Force 1 LV8 Trainer', "Air Force 1 '07 x Space Jam Trainer", 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Crib Air Force 1 Trainer', 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer', 'Womens Air Force 1 Pixel Trainer', 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer'] ['£99.99', '£99.99', '£57.99', '£54.99', '£99.99', '£99.99', '£64.99', '£44.99', '£69.99', '£44.99', '£99.99', '£109.99', '£64.99', '£99.99', '£109.99', '£39.99', '£27.99', '£37.99', '£109.99', '£39.99']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super useful. I copied your exact 2nd code snippet, however print(names, price) still returns two empty lists as [ ] [ ], how can I fix this? @cruisepandey. Is there anyway for me to get it to return the lists filed with both the names and prices? Unless I have misundertsood something, I assumed the .append() code would added to these.

Comment: Are you sure that you have copy the correct code ?

Comment: I think so. I have written: `names = []
    price = []
    for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@data-nq-product-name]"):
        names.append(name.text)
        price.append(name.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-nq-product-name]/../../following-sibling::div").text)
    print(names, price)` @cruisepandey

Comment: instead `names.append(name.text)`, try with `print(name.text)` and see if something get printed ?

Comment: Still nothing :/ I have no idea why. Maybe I'm missing something obvious? No error, just empty or code compiles fine.

Comment: okay, there's a cookie close button, are you using selenium to close that ?

Comment: @user8981199 : anyway, I have updated the code above, and it works just fine on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.footasylum.com/page/search/?term=Nike%20Air%20Force%201')
p = driver.page_source
from bs4 import *
soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')
[[x.text.strip() for x in x.findAll('div')] for x in soup.find('div', {'data-nq-property-value':'search'}).findAll('div', class_='listing-text')]
```

Based on your comment:

`soup.find('div', {'data-nq-property-value':'search'})` will return the div that contains the search result. Each search result has a unique div with a class name `listing-text` that contains the text you are looking for `brand name, shoes model and price`. This div contains three divs with no class that is retrieved by `.findAll('div')`. Text of each div is then striped and you finally the all three item in a single list.
This can be re-written as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.footasylum.com/page/search/?term=Nike%20Air%20Force%201')
p = driver.page_source
from bs4 import *
soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')
results_text = soup.find('div', {'data-nq-property-value':'search'}).findAll('div', class_='listing-text')
for item in results_text:
    texts = item.findAll('div')
    brand = texts[0].text.strip()
    name = texts[1].text.strip()
    price = texts[2].text.strip()
    print([brand, name, price])
```

The result should be:

```
[['Nike', 'Air Force 1 Low SOS Trainer', '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Infant Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£44.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Air Force 1 LV8 Trainer', '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Junior Air Force 1 GS ‘Bred’ Low Trainer', '£54.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Junior Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£57.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Infant Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£44.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Junior Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£64.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Junior Air Force 1 Crater Flyknit Trainer', '£69.99'],
 ['Nike', "Womens Air Force 1 '07 Trainer", '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', "Junior Air Force 1 Low 'Space Jam' Trainer", '£64.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Womens Air Force 1 Pixel Trainer', '£109.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Womens Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£89.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Womens Air Force 1 Trainer', '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Air Force 1 Mid Trainer', '£109.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Air Force 1 LV8 Trainer', '£99.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£37.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£39.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Nursery Air Force 1 Low Trainer', '£39.99'],
 ['Nike', 'Crib Air Force 1 Trainer', '£27.99']]
```

Comment: I think I may prefer this method (of combining selenium and bs4, rather than using just pure selenium). Can you explain to me what exactly the last line of your code snippet does though? @idar

Comment: I just made an edit to answer your question.